# Run notification depends on the user input

Tags: android, service, notifications

I want to run the notification on android depends on date and time inserted by the user 
I know how can I started the notification from activity but i think that not what I'm looking for,
can anyone help me with some codes?

Comment: use the AlarmManager to do stuff at specific times: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is idea how can you achieve this you have to add alarm on that particular time which is selected by user

```
public class TimerReceiverSyncInterval extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("TAG", "Sync OnReceive--");



    scheduleAlarms(context);
    context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationServiceSyncInterval.class));

}

public static void scheduleAlarms(Context paramContext) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    String[] splited = Utility.mPrefs.getSyncTime().split("\\s+");
    if (Utility.mPrefs.getSyncTime().contains("Minute")) {

        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(splited[0]));
    } else if (Utility.mPrefs.getSyncTime().contains("Hour")) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(splited[0]));
    }

    AlarmManager localAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) paramContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent localPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(paramContext, 0,
            new Intent(paramContext, NotificationServiceSyncInterval.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (Utility.mPrefs.getSyncTime().contains("Minute")) {

        localAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                Integer.parseInt(splited[0]) * (60 * 1000), localPendingIntent);

    } else if (Utility.mPrefs.getSyncTime().contains("Hour")) {

        localAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                Integer.parseInt(splited[0]) * (60 * 60 * 1000), localPendingIntent);

    }


}

}
```

And for handle/call notification

```
public class NotificationServiceSyncInterval extends IntentService {

public NotificationServiceSyncInterval() {
    super("Sync Tracker Online");

}

public NotificationServiceSyncInterval(String paramString) {
    super(paramString);

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Sync Handler call");
        callNotification();

}

public static void callNotification() {
    //Notification code
}
}
```

Comment: This is just example for your understanding not exact what you want,you can avoid my local Utility class and just consider your user input for set alarm and one more thing say thanks in comment is not good way in stack if it helps just accept mark or upvote it.